# *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: makefile

I searched this error online and found that I had to use tabs to indent rather than spaces. After fixing this however I am still getting the same error. Apparently the error is on line 2.

```
   # Final program
   holiday: holiday.o queue.o graph.o
       gcc -o holiday holiday.o queue.o graph.o
   # Queue functions
   queue.o: queue.c queue.h
       gcc -c -Wall queue.c
   # Graph functions
   graph.o: graph.c graph.h
       gcc -c -Wall graph.c
   # Main
   holiday.o: holiday.c holiday.h
       gcc -c -Wall holiday.c
```

Comment: Also holiday.h #includes queue.h and graph.h, and all these files are in the same directory.

Comment: Check that the line endings are consistent for the platform on which you're running. ie All lines should have consistent \r\n or \n endings.

Comment: Try a simpler makefile. One rule, no prerequisites, one-line recipe: `@echo hello`.

Comment: If the beginning of each of those `gcc` lines is a single tab character then that looks like it should be working. Check that. Space-tab will still cause that parsing error.

Comment: Ahh I finally managed to fix it, I tried using a different text editor (changed from Mobatexteditor to jEdit) and it somehow magically fixed everything... Thanks for your help =)

Comment: Maybe mobatexteditor had longer tab width?

Comment: Clearly this editor (mobatexteditor) is "helpfully" converting TAB characters into spaces for you.  How nice.  Unless you can find some preferences setting that will turn off this behavior, this editor is completely unsuitable for writing makefiles.